# Only one 'model' statement is allowed in a file (Pagination)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

So my Index view renders the view called StudentWellnessReviews retrieves reviews from the dbo.Review Table. Everything was working until I tried to setup pagination for the StudentWellnessReviews view in the ReviewsController. The error was:
 Only one 'model' statement is allowed in a file.

ReviewsController

```
public class ReviewsController : Controller
{
    private SizaData_1Entities db = new SizaData_1Entities();

// GET: Reviews
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

//Student Wellness Reviews 
public ActionResult StudentWellnessReviews(int page = 1, int pageSize = 4)
{
    using (var context = new SizaData_1Entities())
    {

        List<Review> listReviews = context.Reviews.SqlQuery("select * from dbo.Review where WellnessService='Student Wellness Service'").ToList();
        PagedList<Review> userreview = new PagedList<Review>(listReviews, page, pageSize);
        return View(userreview);
    }
}
```

StudentWellnessReviews View:

```
    @model IEnumerable<Siza.Models.Review>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "";
}

@model PagedList.IPagedList<Siza.Models.Review>
@using PagedList.Mvc;


            <table class="table text-center width:50%">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h5>Username</h5>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                <div align="left">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username)</div>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h5>Wellness Service</h5>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                <div align="left">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WellnessService)</div>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h5>Rating</h5>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                <div align="left">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)</div>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h5>Feedback</h5>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                <div align="left"> @Html.TextAreaFor(modelItem => item.Feedback, new {@readonly = true})</div>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h5>Date Created</h5>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                <div align="left"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)</div>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="2"><hr class="active"/></td></tr>

                }

                @Html.PagedListPager(Model, Page => Url.Action("StudentWellnessReviews", 
               new { Page, pageSize = Model.PageSize} ))
                Showing @Model.FirstItemOnPage to @Model.LastItemOnPage of @Model.TotalItemCount Reviews

            </table>
```

Part of Index view

```
    @using Siza.Controllers


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@{Html.RenderAction("StudentWellnessReviews", "Reviews");}
```

Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you cannot define model for your View multiple times, right n ow you are saying that your view is strongly typed with both `IEnumerable<Siza.Models.Review>` and `PagedList.IPagedList<Siza.Models.Review>` which cannot be, so what i see is you just need `PagedList.IPagedList<Siza.Models.Review>` so remove the top line where you are setting model to `IEnumerable<Siza.Models.Review>` to be like:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Siza.Models.Review>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "";
}
.................
Your rest view
```

Comment: not work for me it reject removing @modelIEnumerable<Siza.Models.Review>